# Use a fitted econometric/statistical model to solve a non linear equation

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

How I can use a fitted non-linear econometric model to solve a non-linear equation?

For example, suppose that I have fitted this regression:

```
a*X + b*X^2 + delta*Z + c  (equation 1)
```

where `a`, `b`, `delta`, `c`, are the estimated coefficients, and `z` is the set of other controls used in the regression.

I want after estimating the equation to use this model and then solve the following non-linear equation:

```
`a*X + b*X^2 + delta*Z + c = f*X` (equation 2)
```

I want to solve for `X`

Is there any automatic or efficient way where I can use the statistical/econometric model to solve the non-linear equation using some non-linear solver?

I think the best method is to reformulate the regression into the following matrix form to solve the equation, such as `AX=X`. But I don't know how to do it in **R**

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: how did you fit the regression? that means you already have X. are you trying to solve for X or `f`?

Comment: I am trying to solve for X. The regression helps to get the coefficients. Equation 1 is the fitted regression. Then I want to use this to solve the system in (2). Basically, I am equation 1 with the RHS of equation 2.

Comment: X is a matrix/ vector. Also, f is unknown, it can be taken into a. so i dont know how you want to approach this. you said you computed the regression coefficients. how did you do that without X??

Comment: f is known. If it helps assume the `delta*Z + c` are constants and known. X can be a matrix / vector.